# Macro for adding unique records to archive in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I work as a salesman and I wanted to create a simple macro in Excel VBA to track my sales.

I added a few combo boxes which compose all the options an order can include and I simply want the button ADD to transfer all the cells(9) within the named range to another named range that is below. That's easy and I do it with this:

```
Range("start").Value = Range("order").Value
```

---

That's the Range("order"), it's 9 columns.

ABC123456789    YES NO  NO  NO  1   0   1   £5.50

---

What I want is to add orders with a Button_Click(), starting with the Range("start"), and adding each order in the next row, so that after a few clicks I've got a few orders archived like this:

ABC123456789    YES NO  NO  NO  1   0   1   £5.50
ABC123456789    YES NO  NO  NO  1   0   1   £5.50
ABC123456789    YES NO  NO  NO  1   0   1   £5.50
ABC123456789    YES NO  NO  NO  1   0   1   £5.50

---

I know this is very easy to do, but I've tried a lot of different things and none of them worked, so if you would be so kind as to help me with this, I'd really appreciate it.

I've already wasted like 5 hours on it and it's embarrassing. I know I'm no programmer, but I used to be able to play with easy little codes like this...

Obviously I want this macro to do more things, like for example I'd like to group the sales by day, but if I can just understand better how the addressing of the cells work together with their properties, I'll definitely figure it out.

Comment: use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to test if the order is already in the range. Additionally you're going to need to either include more of your code or some sample data, otherwise we can't really help you with what you've given us.

Comment: thank you dwirony. I added sample data. Thanks for the `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`, that helps, but what I'm struggling with is addressing the specific cell within the range

Comment: and especially how to create the loop that will add the next order in the next row of the range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    With Range("start")
        .Offset(IIf(IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1)), 0, IIf(IsEmpty(.Cells(2, 1)), 1, .End(xlDown).Row - .Row + 1))).Value = Range("order").Value
    End With
End Sub
```